# Android with WSDL web service

Tags: android

How can i access a WSDL web service in android .Can any one give some code or tutorial for how to implement it on Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call SOAP web service with Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297586/how-to-call-soap-web-service-with-android)

Answer (score 0):

Use a SOAP library like [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) (may be overkill) or [ksoap-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use KSOAP, [this could be usefull to you](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2010/12/call-soap-webservices-without-using-any.html). [And this to send and display the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap).

The first step is to trying the connection to your webservice. You can use **soapUI** which is a very good tool to test soap query.

There is some code example on [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926620/soap-very-large-xml-response-outofmemoryerror), you only need to know your query.