# How to get last sent HTTP request android

Tags: java, android, apache

I am trying to send a GET request to the web server from the android device, the server is having digest authentication enabled, I am able to authenticate using following sort of code,

```
HttpHost host = new HttpHost(urlObj.getHost(), -1, null);
CredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
cp.setCredentials(scope, creds);
HttpContext credContext = new BasicHttpContext();
credContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, cp);
```

Now my problem is every time when I call httpClient.execute() function it first send request without authentication header and then second time with proper headers. So is there any way I can instruct HttpClient to send authentication details by default?

One way is to store the last sent request but, I am also not able to get the last sent request. Any suggestion on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I go the solution, I used the PreemptiveAuth class and most important thing is, I am now creating only one connection to server and reusing the same for all requests.

Answer (score 0):

You may use *HttpURLConnection* to save all the params you need. I use it and [display my source code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926620/soap-very-large-xml-response-outofmemoryerror).

url_connection is defined like that

> private HttpURLConnection url_connection; // WebService Connection
>
> url_connection= (HttpURLConnection) new URL(your_url_server).openConnection();
>
> url_connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
> url_connection.setDoInput(true);
> url_connection.setDoOutput(true);
> ....