# java.lang.outofmemoryerror even though their is no images

Tags: android

I am not using any images in my activity other than google ads. but I getting java.lang.outofmemoryerror and app is getting crash.

here is the logcat

```
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.push(KXmlParser.java:626)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText(KXmlParser.java:865)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:354)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1385)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:210)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:366)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:233)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:366)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:121)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList.SendRequesttoServer(RestaurantsList.java:207)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList$ListData.doInBackground(RestaurantsList.java:148)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList$ListData.doInBackground(RestaurantsList.java:1)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-25 18:24:22.125: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  ... 4 more
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277): Activity com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43f0d2e8 that was originally added here
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43f0d2e8 that was originally added here
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList$ListData.onPreExecute(RestaurantsList.java:159)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList.onCreate(RestaurantsList.java:83)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my AsyncTask class where i am getting the error

```
public class ListData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog.dismiss();
        try {
            if (!lstresponse.isEmpty()) {
                lstresult.addAll(lstresponse);
                GlobVariables.restaurant_response = lstresult;
                lst_restaurant.setAdapter(CustAdapter);
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No result found for" + " " + check,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SendRequesttoServer(params);
        return "1";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(RestaurantsList.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

    }

}

public void SendRequesttoServer(String[] params) {
    try {
        if (GlobVariables.MenuSelectd.equals("Cuisine")
                || GlobVariables.Selecteditem.equals("Cuisines")) {
            METHOD = "GetRestaurantsByCuisines";

            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            request.addProperty("cuisineName", params[0]);
            request.addProperty("cityName", params[1]);
        } else if (GlobVariables.MenuSelectd.equals("locations")
                || GlobVariables.Selecteditem.equals("Location")) {
            METHOD = "GetRestaurantsByLocations";
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            request.addProperty("location", params[0]);
            request.addProperty("cityName", params[1]);
        } else if (GlobVariables.Selecteditem.equals("ByName")) {
            METHOD = "GetRestaurantsByName";
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            request.addProperty("restaurantName", params[0]);
            request.addProperty("cityName", params[1]);

        } else {
            METHOD = "SearchRestaurant";
            request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
            request.addProperty("searchParameter", params[0]);
            request.addProperty("cityName", params[1]);
        }

        SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD;

        // SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
        // request.addProperty("location", params[0]);
        // request.addProperty("cityName", params[1]);
        check = params[0];
        SoapSerializationEnvelope res = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        res.dotNet = true;
        res.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE call = new HttpTransportSE(url);

        SoapPrimitive result;
        call.call(SOAP_ACTION, res);
        result = (SoapPrimitive) res.getResponse();
        ParseDetails Objparsecities = new ParseDetails(
                new ByteArrayInputStream(result.toString()
                        .getBytes("UTF-8")));
        lstresponse = Objparsecities.parse();
        System.out.println(lstresponse.size());

    } catch (SoapFault e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can i know why i am getting java.lang.outofmemoy error and what's the mistake i am doing?

Thanks:)

Comment: using static or activity context from another activtiy or class in your current activity?

Comment: @Raghunandan from another activity

Comment: What's on this line RestaurantsList.java:207 ?

Comment: if u r using static variables a lot may lead to memory leaks. Can u post you asynctask code full?

Comment: @Anup  call.call(SOAP_ACTION, res); this is at line no 207

Comment: @Raghunandan i have added my aynctask class

Answer (score 0):

In Android every application is allocated a **VM Budget**. The VM Budget is the maximum amount of memory any application can use. This memory limit includes everything, Bitmaps(even though it is created on the external heap), objects, etc. Whenever, an application exceeds this limit OOM exception is thrown.

**The value of the VM budget ranges from 16MB to 80MB or more. It depends on the device.**

Even printing huge amount of logs can lead to OOM issues, i have tested that myself.

Also in your case the logs clearly states the dialog which you add in `onPreExecute` Method in your async task is leaking. Are you handling orientation changes in your activity ?

> > 03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277): Activity com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43f0d2e8 that was originally added here
> >
> > 03-25 18:24:22.485: E/WindowManager(277): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.netserv.Pungry.RestaurantsList has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43f0d2e8 that was originally added here

If you are not dealing with the orientation changes then for each change in orientation the activity will be created again and `onCreate` will be executed, which creates a possibility that the async task is triggered again and again. This can also lead to a higher memory utilization.

*How big is your sever response, I have had experience with a server response which was huge 50,000+ nodes, which was causing issues in the long run.*

Are you using an external lib for parsing the XML data ? I would suggest writing a simple SAX parser instead of that, it will reduce the number of object creation and also the control remains in your own code

Comment: i am using sax parser for parsing and my response contains more than 50k+ nodes. and i am not handling an orientation changes in my activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are sending/receiving large amounts of data via SOAP requests using ksoap2. `OutOfMemoryError` is caused whenever memory is exceeded. It is not necessary that images must be present in your app for this to happen.

Problems like this using this library have been reported before. The solutions in this thread might be of use to you:

[Very large SOAP response - Android- out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941581/very-large-soap-response-android-out-of-memory-error/12732396#12732396)