# Issue with ksoap2 library: OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2

I am using `ksoap2` library in android for implementing soap webservices.
Now this works well when the data to be downloaded is small (few kb/mb's).
But when the response is large it gives me `OutOfMemoryError` after the below loc,

```
HttpTransportSE.call(ACTION,SoapSerializationEnvelope);
```

I know that this is caused due to low heap space.
I have read same post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941581/very-large-soap-response-android-out-of-memory-error).

But there may be some other way instead of customizing the `HttpTransportSE` class itself (In ref to above link ).

below is the ss:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two strategies to help you solve this problem:

-**Save your SOAP XML stream directly to disk as you download it. Don't store it in memory.**

-**Parse it using a SAX-style parser, where you don't load the whole DOM in memory, but rather parse it in chunks.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you pls provide information on how to save SOAP xml to disk rather memory.

Comment: My other issue is: 1) Can I get SOAP response xml before `HttpTransportSE.call(ACTION,SoapSerializationEnvelope);`. 2)Storing  soap xml response in disk .. does ksoap2 allows the same (to not store response in memory)?