# ksoap2 OutOfMemory exception

Tags: android, web-services, out-of-memory, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm calling a service which returns a large amount of data (~ 23 Mb) using ksoap2 for Android. It takes a long time trying to get the response and then throws "**Out of memory exception**".

Did anyone had the same problem, or have any idea/suggestion how to deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you will need to split up the data or do some streaming

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941581/very-large-soap-response-android-out-of-memory-error/12732396#12732396