# Ksoap2 android Outofmemory error for huge amount of data

Tags: android, web-services, out-of-memory, ksoap2

I have searched lot of on google and found one solution. I have also tried that solution but still i got same error.Help me if anyone have solution for this problem. I got following error during webservice  call.

```
'Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1345)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:269)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:431)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:301)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:431)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:147)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:338)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:311)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:125)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:120)
at com.example.helper.HelperFunctions.getAccountList(HelperFunctions.java:293)
at com.example.profiler.SyncData$GetProfiler.doInBackground(SyncData.java:269)
at com.example.profiler.SyncData$GetProfiler.doInBackground(SyncData.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 3 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:271)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.readValue(KXmlParser.java:1345)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:390)
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:269)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:431)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:301)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:431)
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:147)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:129)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.parseResponse(HttpTransportSE.java:338)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:311)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:125)
at com.example.helper.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:120)
at com.example.helper.HelperFunctions.getAccountList(HelperFunctions.java:293)
at com.example.profiler.SyncData$GetProfiler.doInBackground(SyncData.java:269)
at com.example.profiler.SyncData$GetProfiler.doInBackground(SyncData.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)'
```

Comment: use  android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file

Comment: yes i have already added this line into manifest. But still getting same error.

Comment: I tried this solution  from this link but when i  getting large response then again this error occurs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941581/very-large-soap-response-android-out-of-memory-error/12732396#12732396

Answer (score 0):

Do u have used "bitmap" on your activity ?or load many data on your activity?
and u can use `Bitmap.recycle();`and `System.gc();`  at right time.
Hope that helps :).

Comment: no i haven't used bitmap when i am syncing data.
Here soap webservice call made for response.
But response is too large above 50 MB.