# OutofMemory parsing SOAP using wsdl2code

Tags: android, xml-parsing, out-of-memory, android-ksoap2, wsdl2code

I have generated a Soap client from wsdl2code , that used XMLPullParser to parse the response. I am getting a 30 Mb file as response, 
and OutofMemory exception while parsing.

What is a best way to avoid this exception, I have already downloaded the response from server and kept in internal storage of device as suggested in this link [Very large SOAP response - Android- out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941581/very-large-soap-response-android-out-of-memory-error)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android:largeHeap="true"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap) to request a larger heap size.

The only way to have as large a limit as possible is to do memory intensive tasks via the NDK, as the NDK does not impose memory limits like the SDK.